# In React-Redux app, trying to pre-fill the default value in Edit Component with current api calls value

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my reactredux app, There is a peculiar situaton where I am currently trying to pre-fill my input field in Edit component but the thing is ,Its getting filled but not with current api calls but with last api calls that happens inside componentDidMount().I tried to clear the object too but all in vain. Kindly suggest

ProfileEdit.js component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {profileFetchDetail} from '../actions/profile';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProfileEdit extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         firstName: '',
         lastName: '',
         emailId: '',
      }
   }
  componentDidMount(){
      const id = this.props.match.params.id;
      this.props.profileFetchDetail(id);
      this.setState({
         firstName: this.props.profile.firstName,
         lastName: this.props.profile.lastName,
         emailId: this.props.profile.emailId
      })
  }

 render() {
    const {firstName,lastName,emailId} = this.state;
    console.log(this.props.profile);
  return (
   <form name="profileCreate" className="profile-form">
      <div className="form-control">
         <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label><br/>
         <input type="text" id="firstName" defaultValue={firstName}
          name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" 
           />
      </div>

      <div className="form-control">
         <label htmlFor="LastName">Last Name</label><br/>
         <input type="text" id="LastName" defaultValue={lastName}
            name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" 

            />
      </div>

      <div className="form-control">
         <label htmlFor="email">Email</label><br/>
         <input type="email" id="email" defaultValue={emailId}
             />
      </div>

      <div className="form-action">
         <input type="submit" value="Click here"  />
      </div>

   </form>
  )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   profile: state.profile.profile
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {profileFetchDetail})(withRouter(ProfileEdit));
```

Action creators, here profileFetchDetail() is of our interest

```
import api from '../api';

// profile create
export const profileAdd = (formData, history) => async dispatch => {
    console.log(formData);
     const config = {
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      }

     try {
       await api.post('/api/profile/create', formData, config);
       dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROFILE', payload: formData });
       history.push('/list');
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
     }
}



// profile get all list
export const profileFetch = () => async dispatch => {

  try {
    const res = await api.get('/api/profile/list');
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_PROFILE', payload: res.data });
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
}

// profile get single list item corresponding to id
export const profileFetchDetail = (id) => async dispatch => {

  dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_PROFILE' });
  try {
    const res = await api.get(`/api/profile/${id}`);
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_PROFILE_SINGLE', payload: res.data });
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
}

// profile delete
export const profileDelete = (id) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_PROFILE' });
  try {
    const res = await api.delete(`/api/profile/${id}/delete`);
    dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_PROFILE', payload: res.data });
    dispatch(profileFetch());
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
}
```

ProfileReducers

```
const initialState = {
   profiles:[],
   profile:{}
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'CREATE_PROFILE':
     return {...state, profiles: [...state.profiles, action.payload]};

  case 'GET_PROFILE':
       return {...state, profiles: action.payload};

  case 'GET_PROFILE_SINGLE':
       return {...state, profile: action.payload};

  case 'CLEAR_PROFILE':
       return {...state, profile: {}};

  case 'DELETE_PROFILE':
       return {...state, profiles: state.profiles.filter( item => item._id !== action.payload) };
  default:
     return state;
 }

};
```

First time it loads perfectly on clicking edit button then the issue happens on clicking any other edit button.Pasting the example of 2 api calls inside componentDidMount().

In the attached image, the last api request in sequence displayed is the currently made request.[Api made detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GJwG.png) 
Note: Till now I am not trying to edit it just prefilling data,where issue happening.

Comment: @Dan Abramov kindly suggest.

Comment: @Christopher Ngo kindly suggest